# Javascript get element by ID .action returning empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html document in a javascript file, I then narrow it down to the element I am looking for using `var element = html.getElementById(inputForm);` which returns this part (All correct so far),

```
<form class="add" id="inputForm" action="/submit-form/7265283" method="post">
```

However when I then try to extract the 'Action' part using

```
var url = element.action;
```

I get a blank string returned, not `undefined`/`null`, a blank string. What is confusing me, even more, is that doing `console.log(element.method);` successfully returns 'post'. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have a html file saved in the variable html, it's not throwing an error

Comment: Using this code,  `var itemHTML = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");` , i am saving the html document

Comment: But, given that `console.log(element.method);` works, obviously something's working, somehow, so i guess we can move past that

Comment: Are you sure `element` is the form you think it is? `action` is a property, so `element.action` should have worked just fine. The fact that it gives you an empty string suggests that it IS working fine, and it is in fact empty.

Comment: yes, if i console log element i get the exact form im trying to select

Comment: You should be able to create a re-creatable test case for us that you can include in your question that recreates the problem. Doing so would help. As given, your code works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/skpbppub/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like .action is only a 'setter' in this context.

While MDN does specify that it can be used to 'get' the 'action' property's value, it only returns a blank string. Even more perplexing is that it still returns an empty string after updating the element by using .action to set a new value.

Here's an odd workaround:

```
<form id='inputForm' action='some-action.script'></form>

var element = document.getElementById('inputForm');
var action = element.attributes.action.value;

console.log(action);
--> 'some-action.script'
```

Comment: Are you sure .action is working correctly in reference to his question? It doesn't seem to be only grabbing the actual 'action' property's value from the form element. In fact its outputting a URI string with the .action value as an endpoint so to speak ('foo' is catted on the end). Seems like an interesting characteristic of the DOM api.